# How to run gradle commands in Android Studio terminal?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, terminal, build.gradle

I am having dependency conflict in my project. So, I want to see the dependency tree first. But commands are not working. I am using `windows` operating system. Is there any settings option I need to change? Or use any plugin to observe dependency conflict?

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        def nav_version = "2.3.0-beta01"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

}
```

[image: terminal commands]

Answer (score 0):

If you are a windows users then in terminal type
gradlew task-name
if your are mac user the type
./gradlew task-name

task name maybe of your requirement like if you want to debug then taskname will be assembleDebug
or if you need to install the apk on to emulator the it would be installDebug

Comment: what about `gradlew app:dependencies --scan` command? It's not working. Is there any change to be made in the shell executable path?

Comment: You could add dependencies and then sync the project.Im not sure if we could alter dependency using terminal [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies) check this I went through this but i couldn't get terminal command too alter dependencies Sorry

Comment: I have solved it by clearing all the caches of the IDE. At first I tried by running `invalidate caches and restart`. But it didn't solve. Thanks